# why is this php code running without declaring variable global inside function?

Tags: php, forms, function, scope

this code is running and giving output but my question is why am I able to access variables abc and def from inside function pali when I haven't used global keyword?

```
<form action=palindrome.php method=post>
<input type="text"  name="number" type=submit> 
</form>
<?php
 $a=$b=0;
 $abc= $def = $_POST["number"];
 echo "$def</br>";
 function pali()
 { while($abc>=1)
   { $a=$abc%10  ;
     $b=$b*10+ $a ;
     $abc= $abc/10;
   }
   if($def==$b)
   echo '$def is palindrome '.$def ;
   else 
   echo '$def is not a palindrome '.$def;
   echo "<br>$b";
}
 pali();
 ?>
```

Comment: Even broken clock shows correct time twice a day. And here's a fiddle that shows __incorrect__ result and a lot of notices: https://3v4l.org/4DsBo

Comment: Side note: It's best to quote everything in form elements.

Comment: `type="text"` _AND_ `type=submit` on one `<input>` element?

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the top.
Your HTML attributes which contain strings, should be enclosed in strings, like so:

```
<form action="palindrome.php" method="POST">
```

You can't define multiple type attributes on an -Tag: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input
You'll have to create multiple elements:

```
<input type="text" name="number"> 
<input type="submit" name="submit">
```

The following lines are vulneralbe to Cross-site scripting (XSS). You **MUST** learn and prevent XSS (and other) before publishing actual web apps.

```
$abc= $def = $_POST["number"];
echo "$def</br>";
```

Quick Explanation: You are outputting the content of the variable `$def`, which is equal to what the user sent with a HTTP Post Request with the field name `"number"`. The user can send anything to you and you will echo it. Meaning: I can send you valid HTML, which you will echo out and my Browser will evaluate it as HTML, because he was no reason to belive that it is anything other than what you wanted to do.

Addressing your function and variable scope. If you want to use variables from other code inside your function (there are exceptions in Object Oriented Programming [OOP] etc.) you need to pass them inside the function as an argument: https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php
You would define your function like so:

```
function pali($a, $b, $abc, $def) { /* (Your logic goes here) */ }
```

And you would call your function like so:

```
pali($a, $b, $abc, $def);
```

I will have to point out that your function is again vulnerable to Cross-site scripting (XSS).

```
echo '$def is palindrome '.$def ;
else 
echo '$def is not a palindrome '.$def;
echo "<br>$b";
```

You echo out again any contents inside your variable. However the first `$def` in the first 2 echo's won't echo out the content, rather the text $def since you did use single quotes. If you try to echo the content of a variable inside single quotes it won't work, only with double quotes.
Writing insecure applications is ok if you are in a process of learning, but later, before publishing an app, you will need to learn about web app security basics (SQLi, XSS, ...).